# La altura de un slide no se ajusta a pantalla

Tags: css, img, height, slide, swiper

estoy haciendo un web con un slide y el problema que tengo es que no se ajusta verticalmente. Cuando hago la pantalla pequeña queda un espacio en blanco por debajo. Debería quedar como esta web: https://cokebartrina.com/, que se ajusta perfectamente centrando la imagen al hacer la pantalla mas grande o mas pequeña.

Aqui el codigo:

```
      <div class="swiper" id="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img 
             src="assets/img/WEB_01.jpg"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img 
             src="assets/img/WEB_02.jpg"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img 
             src="assets/img/WEB_03.jpg"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img 
             src="assets/img/WEB_05.jpg"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img 
             src="assets/img/WEB_06.jpg"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img 
             src="assets/img/WEB_07.jpg"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img 
             src="assets/img/WEB_08.jpg"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img 
             src="assets/img/WEB_09.jpg"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img 
             src="assets/img/WEB_09_PLUS.jpg"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img 
             src="assets/img/WEB_10.jpg"></div>

          </div>

       </div>
```

Y el css:

```
    html,
    body {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
    }

    img {
     width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Para que una imagen sea responsiva debe tener width: 100% height: auto o viceversa. En tu caso deberia ocupar el 100% de altura asi que deberias usar la opcion viceversa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El efecto que tu buscas, al menos de mi parte lo pude lograr de la siguiente forma:

En vez de usar una tag img le pongo directamente la imagen con la propiedad css background-image, cover lo que logra es que tome toda la pantalla y center center como imaginaras centra la imagen tanto en x como en y

```css
html,
    body {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .swiper-slide, .swiper, .swiper-wrapper{
     height: 100%;
     width: auto;
    }
    .swiper-slide{
     background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any");
     background-size:cover;
     background-position: center center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="swiper" id="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

No obstante, al igual que los de la web que pusiste como enlace, si el personaje no esta centrado y ocupa toda la altura vas a tener recortes. No se si sera lo que buscas pero el comportamiento es como el del ejemplo que diste. Saludos!